# whats the best approach to detect button click and then open trades?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I have written a simple trading pannel which will open trades based on button clicks but I just noticed that sometimes it would open trades automatically , even though I havent clicked any button.

here is what the code looks like :

```
void OnChartEvent(const int id,const long& lparam,const double& dparam,const string& sparam)
  { 
   string btnclick = sparam;
   string btntoreset = sparam;
   if(Risk != 0  )
     {
      LotSize = GetLots(Risk,Sl);
      if(StringFind(btnclick,"Buy ",0)>=0) //I have multiple buy buttons and Here I am finding if a buy button was clicked.
        {
         StringReplace(btnclick,"Buy ",""); // Here I am replacing the "Buy " word from the name of the button because the names of the buy buttons are like this: Buy 2, Buy 4, Buy 6 
         int NbrOfTrades =(int) btnclick; // Here I am trying to see how many trades to open
         for(int i=0; i<NbrOfTrades; i++)
           {
            RefreshRates();
            if(!OrderSend(Symbol(),0,LotSize,Ask,100,Ask-Sl*Point,Ask+Tp*Point,NULL,(int)magicnum))
              {
               Print("Error: ",GetLastError()," during opening the market order.");
              }
           }
         ObjectSetInteger(0,btntoreset, OBJPROP_STATE, 0);
        }
      if(StringFind(btnclick,"Sell ",0)>=0)
        {
         StringReplace(btnclick,"Sell ","");
         int NbrOfTrades =(int) btnclick;
         for(int i=0; i<NbrOfTrades; i++)
           {
            RefreshRates();
            if(!OrderSend(Symbol(),1,LotSize,Ask,100,Bid+Sl*Point,Ask-Tp*Point,NULL,(int)magicnum))
              {
               Print("Error: ",GetLastError()," during opening the market order.");
              }
           }
         ObjectSetInteger(0,btntoreset, OBJPROP_STATE, 0);
        }
     }  
  }
```

I have tried to recreate the issue , but I have no Idea what causes this problem , and which way I should go to solve this , I know some thing is wrong with my approach, but just cant figure out what i am doing wrong